# Sending coordinates to an URL POST each five minutes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to send coordinates to a web server in each five minutes. I'm doing this way:

In the `-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` I have variables (declared in the .h file) receiving the information I want to send by the post.

And I have a NSTimer calling a method wich initiates this:

```
{
    ASIFormDataRequest * request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostValue:myValue forKey:@"myKey"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=%@", @"UTF-8"]];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

The app crashes when the timer calls the function to send data.

Anyone, please, can help me?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the crash?

Comment: When using **ASIFormDataRequest** you do not need to set the request header, this is done for you based on the type of data you are posting. It is entirely possible this is causing the crash.

Also, you need to explain what value is contained in the variable *myValue*. If it is anything other than the most basic of types (*int, float, NSString etc*) then this is the most probable cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what code you've given us, the only place the problem can be is in the serialization of `myValue`. Since we have no idea what that object is, we can't do much other than make broad suggestions. `myValue` needs to be a string, encoded such that it is safe to submit as a form value. URL encoded, XML, or even JSON would work. [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) and [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/) both have good serializer implementations you could base on.

The important thing to realize is that you can't add an arbitrary object to the post values of ASIFormDataRequest unless you've built some plumbing around your objects and ASI* to make it format your objects for HTTP.